# React Antd table rendering before data is populated

Tags: reactjs, render, antd

I am new to react and I am attempting to populate an ant design table component through my api call, except it seems the table renders before the api call can finish grabbing the data. I attempted some conditional rendering but that didn't seem to help. Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { Table } from 'antd';
import { workOrdersTicketsService } from '../../../../services';
import { dispatchTicketColumns } from '../../../../common/utils/grid-columns';

class DispatchTicketTable extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      id: 0,
      loading: true,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.id > 0 && this.state.id !== null) {
      this.getDispatchTickets();
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps !== null && this.props.id !== null
      && prevProps.id !== this.props.id) {
      this.getDispatchTickets();
    }
  }

  getDispatchTickets() {
    workOrdersTicketsService.get(this.props.id).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
      this.setState({
        data: result.value,
        loading: false,
      });
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Table id={this.props.id} columns={dispatchTicketColumns} dataSource={this.state.data} pagination={false} size="small" />
    );
  }
}

DispatchTicketTable.propTypes = {
  id: PropTypes.number,
};

DispatchTicketTable.defaultProps = {
  id: 0,
};

export { DispatchTicketTable as default };
```

Answer (score 0):

> except it seems the table renders before the api call can finish grabbing the data

If your problem is that your table will render before loading is finished, it should work:

```
  render() {
    return (this.state.loading ? (<div>loading</div>) : (
      <Table id={this.props.id} columns={dispatchTicketColumns} dataSource={this.state.data} pagination={false} size="small" />
    ));
  }
```

if it doesn't work, then the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
render() {
  if (this.state.loading) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <Table id={this.props.id} columns={dispatchTicketColumns} dataSource={this.state.data} pagination={false} size="small" />
  );
}
```

The `render()` method is allowed to return `null`, that simply renders nothing instead of rendering an empty table